# Creating an array of pointers to other pointers

Tags: c++

So how would I create an array which would contain pointers to other arrays, so that I can still access the arrays that the overall array points to? I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{

bool (*arrays)[3], *arr1, *arr2, *arr3, *tempArr;

arr1 = new bool[2];
arr2 = new bool[2];
arr3 = new bool[2];

arr1[0] = arr2[0] = arr3[0] = 0;
arr1[1] = arr2[1] = arr3[1] = 1;

arrays[0] = arr1;
arrays[1] = arr2;
arrays[2] = arr3;

int n = 0;

while (n <= 2) {

    tempArr = arrays[n];

    cout << tempArr[0] << tempArr[1] << "\n";
}
}
```

Also, how would I make the overall array ("arrays") a pointer so that I can add new arrays to it? I made a preliminary function, but it doesn't work (note "paths" is the overall array):

```
void addPath (void)
{

int n = getArrayLength(paths), i = 0;
bool (*newPaths)[n + 1];

while (i < n) {

    newPaths[i] = paths[i];

    ++i;
}

delete [] paths;

newPaths[n] = tempPath;

paths = newPaths;
}
```

Hopefully this isn't to confusing or absurd, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of any of the dozens of questions that appear if you search for "c++ array of pointers"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're looking for `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<bool> > paths;
```

Note,  however, that `std::vector<bool>` isn't a normal "container", and doesn't support all the operations of a normal container like `vector<any_type_other_than_bool>` would.

Answer (score 0):

You could use malloc. Of course, that's kind of C code, not C++:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

size_t ptrArraySize = 3; 
bool** arrays = (bool**) malloc(ptrArraySize * sizeof(bool*));
```

Or, you could do as Jerry Coffin suggested. However, this doesn't give you a vector with pointers to vectors. It gives you a vector of vectors (so stack allocated, not on the heap). To get a vector of pointers to vectors, you could do something like:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<bool> * > ptrVector;
std::vector<bool> * vectorA = new std::vector<bool>();
vectorA->push_back(true);
ptrVector.push_back(vectorA);
```

Another possibility is using one of [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) or [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm), depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`bool (*arrays)[3]` declares `arrays` to be a pointer to an array of 3 bools -- you want an array of 3 pointers to bools, or `bool *arrays[3]`.  To make a pointer to that dynamically, you want just `bool **arrays = new bool*[3];`